# Add text box and animate using rotating string

Tags: javascript

Hi guys our teacher ask us to add in input type="text" and animate it using the rotating string with these codes:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript Basic Animation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function animate_string(id)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        var textNode = element.childNodes[0]; // assuming no other children
        var text = textNode.data;
    setInterval (function ()
    {
    text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring (0, text.length - 1);
    textNode.data = text;
    }, 100);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="animate_string('target')">
    <pre>
    Write a Javascript program to rotate the string 'HELLO WORLD'
    in right direction by periodically removing one letter from
    the end of the string and attaching it to the front.
    </pre>
    <font size="21">
    <pre id="target">HELLO WORLD</pre>
    </font>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but I don't know how. Please help thanks.:)

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = "hello world" ;
l = strlen(s) ;

tmp = substr(s, 1, l-2) + substr(s, 0, 1) ;
s = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need call animate_string('id of element here'); from script.